# How to add delay in excution in Queued Event Listeners in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a Queued event in laravel 5.2, Now I want to add 10 min delay in execution of this event.

Please guide how can I add delay in queued event.

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\NewMessage;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class HandleNewMessage implements ShouldQueue
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(NewMessage $event)
    {

        //Code to send email
    }
}
```

Comment: Any answer of this?

Answer (score 1):

At you Listener
as long as you implement **ShouldQueue**
and use traits **Queueable**, you can assign seconds to the public variable **$delay**

```
public function __construct() {
    //The number of seconds before the job should be made available.
    $this->delay = 10;
}
```